# document.getElement by id returns null

Tags: angular

I am beginner angular 2

Here is my input

```
<input type="hidden" value={{date}} #myname/>
```

Here is my code

`console.log(document.getElementById('myname'));` It's return `null`

why?

Kindly Advise me,

Thanks

Comment: if you are using angular-cli. you can add jquery to you config file and use it instead of document. like $('#myname')

Comment: any other way to fix this issue... : (

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template)

Answer (score 1):

As you defined template variable, you can access that element using `ViewChild` decorator. `document.getElementById` will only work when element has `id` property with specific value in that `id` attribute.

```
@ViewChild('myname') myNameElem: any;
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I used this but my consoled value is undefined.Actually  here is my code. I defined @ViewChild('myname') myNameElem: any; and console.log(this.myNameElem);

Comment: I need get input element value.I tried to many way.But Does not wrk.

Comment: pls refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871031/get-element-value-ng-for

Answer (score 1):

```
import {ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('myname') el:ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit()
{
   //this.el.nativeElement.focus(); 
   //this.el.nativeElement.value()
   // And more

}
```

Comment: I tried this But i am getting this error nativeElement is undefined

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681